# How to insert data to a local html form and display it on webview

Tags: android, html, webview

I want to fill a simple html form stored locally, with data passed with intent and display my html form in a webview in order to print it.

I verified that the data from the intent are passed to my activity but when I try to load data I get empty field. Do far I did the following:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("ServiceName");

    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        is = getAssets().open("form.html");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int size = 0;
    try {
        size = is.available();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    try {
        is.read(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String str = new String(buffer);
    str = str.replace("textarea4", name);


    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

    wv.loadData(str, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "UTF-8");
```

What I am missing here?

Comment: `str = str.replace("textarea4", name);`. We do not know if that works of course. You should show complete input.

Answer (score 0):

All it had to do with the placeholders in html, name="textarea4">Details I had to use Details as placeholder not textarea4